# Multidimensional numpy array appending with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

In Python, I can concatenate two arrays like below,

```
myArray = []

myArray += [["Value1", "Value2"]]
```

I can then access the data by indexing the 2 dimensions of this array like so

```
print(myArray[0][0])
```

which will output:

```
Value1
```

How would I go about achieving the same thing with Numpy?

I tried the numpy append function but that only ever results in single dimensional arrays for me, no matter how many square brackets I put around the value I'm trying to append.

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly conceived front end to `np.concatenate`.  Did you actually read the `np.append` docs?  Pay attention to the `axis` parameter? Don't try to imitate list append with `numpy`. It doesn't operate in-place and is slower.

Comment: One problem with making an array from repeated `np.append` is getting the starting array right, as you found out.  There isn't a simple equivalent to the empty list.  It's better to collect all your arrays in a list, and do **one** `concatenate` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the dimension of the final array then you could use `np.vstack`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([]).reshape(0,2)
>>> b = np.array([['Value1', 'Value2']])
>>> np.vstack([a,b])
array([['Value1', 'Value2']], dtype='<U32')
```

Comment: Huge thanks!

I eventually figured out how to use np.append to do what I needed to do (figuring out the axis parameter helped) but then I was very disappointed that I cannot append a multi-dimensional array to an empty array.

Your ".reshape(0,2)" bit of the code helped solved that problem and now I can achieve what I wanted. 

Thanks again :)